# Error CS0104 'HtmlHelper' is an ambiguous reference between 'PagedList.Mvc.HtmlHelper' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, pagedlist

This error was encountered when I was Writing the `PagedListPager` method. It is showing some ambiguity error. I'm new to this MVC development. I'm not able to figure this out! Any help would be appreciated!

the error is showing for this particular line:
`@HtmlHelper.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }));`

Note: if I try to write it as `Html.PagedListPager(...);` it still gives an error stating that `PagedListPager` is not declared in Html.

Answer (score 0):

If you use just .net mvc add this to your view

```
@using PagedList; 
@using PagedList.Mvc;
```

for .net core

```
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core
@using X.PagedList
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.Common
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors are a bit misleading...

Maybe trying to disable unnecessary usings statements.  The ambiguous references seems to be a result of a compiler bug or feature which gets confused when implicit using and unnecessary usings statements are used.  May work for you, certain did for us.

Affected namespaces:
SDK               Default namespaces
Microsoft.NET.Sdk

- System
- System.Collections.Generic
- System.IO
- System.Linq
- System.Net.Http
- System.Threading
- System.Threading.Tasks

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

- System.Net.Http.Json
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging